# btrfs: Reset `mount -o rw,degraded` count

Tags: mount, btrfs, fsck

With btrfs, it seems that there is a single opportunity to use:

```
-o rw,degraded
```

(eg, if there is a missing disk in a RAID1 configuration)

- How can one force the degraded mount to proceed `rw` a second time?
- How can one edit the filesystem device so as to pretend that it has not yet been mounted `rw,degraded`?

I understand there are kernel patches which remove various mount checks, however I want to patch the filesystem instead, and have all the checks still in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really an answer, but perhaps some leads...

There is a [known gotcha in the wiki](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Gotchas#raid1_volumes_only_mountable_once_RW_if_degraded) which affects btrfs RAID1:

> When a raid1 volume is stuck as read-only [...] it can only be recovered by dumping its contents, recreating it and restoring the contents

But that's just the offical line - there is a simple [kernel patch](https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-btrfs/msg62473.html) which effectively comments out the line:

```
goto fail_sysfs;
```

Which will allow multiple `rw,degraded` mounts.

Please shout if you find a filesystem patch!